# Tensorflow.js tokenizer

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js, nlp

I'm new to Machine Learning and Tensorflow, since I don't know python so I decide to use there javascript version (maybe more like a wrapper).

The **problem** is I tried to build a model that process the Natural Language. So the first step is tokenizer the text in order to feed the data to model. I did a lot research, but most of them are using python version of tensorflow that use method like: `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` which I can't find similar in tensorflow.js. I'm stuck in this step and don't know how can I transfer text to vector that can feed to model. Please help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To transform text to vectors, there are lots of ways to do it, all depending on the use case. The most intuitive one, is the one using the term frequency, i.e , given the vocabulary of the corpus (all the words possible), all text document will be represented as a vector where each entry represents the occurrence of the word in text document.

With this vocabulary :

```
["machine", "learning", "is", "a", "new", "field", "in", "computer", "science"]
```

the following text:

```
["machine", "is", "a", "field", "machine", "is", "is"]
```

will be transformed as this vector:

```
[2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

One of the disadvantage of this technique is that there might be lots of 0 in the vector which has the same size as the vocabulary of the corpus. That is why there are others techniques. However the [**bag of words**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) is often referred to. And there is a slight different version of it using [**tf.idf**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)

```js
const vocabulary = ["machine", "learning", "is", "a", "new", "field", "in", "computer", "science"]
const text = ["machine", "is", "a", "field", "machine", "is", "is"] 
const parse = (t) => vocabulary.map((w, i) => t.reduce((a, b) => b === w ? ++a : a , 0))
console.log(parse(text))
```

There is also the following [module](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural#tokenizers) that might help to achieve what you want

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. So I think only transfer a word to a number is not enough for tensorflow.js to use. The next step should transfer each word to a multi-dimension vector, and I have no idea how to approach it. Also, if you want to do this thing by own, is that mean tensorflow.js doesn't has similar function to use for now?

Comment: tensorflowJs does not have string tokenizer yet. If the answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I like the simplicity of the Keras tokenizer, so I recreated the parts of it that I  need in JavaScript: https://gist.github.com/dlebech/5bbabaece36753f8a29e7921d8e5bfc7 Perhaps this will be useful for others that find this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I faced this issue and handled it by following below steps:

1. After `tokenizer.fit_on_texts([data])` print `tokenizer.word_index` in your python code.
2. copy and save the word_index output as json file.
3. Refer to this json object to generate tokenized words, like this:

   `function getTokenisedWord(seedWord) {
     const _token = word2index[seedWord.toLowerCase()]
     return tf.tensor1d([_token])
   }`
4. Feed to model:

   `const seedWordToken = getTokenisedWord('Hello');
   model.predict(seedWordToken).data().then(predictions => {
     const resultIdx = tf.argMax(predictions).dataSync()[0];
     console.log('Predicted Word ::', index2word[resultIdx]);
   })`
5. `index2word` is the reverse mapping of `word2index` json object.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an npm module for this recently also if it helps anyone.

https://github.com/rjmacarthy/string-tokeniser

Answer (score 0):

```js
const vocabulary = ["machine", "learning", "is", "a", "new", "field", "in", "computer", "science"]
const text = ["machine", "is", "a", "field", "machine", "is", "is"] 
const parse = (t) => vocabulary.map((w, i) => t.reduce((a, b) => b === w ? ++a : a , 0))
console.log(parse(text))
```