# How can you train an LSTM to classify spam in tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

I'm training an LSTM on some spam - I have two classes: "spam" and "ham". I preprocess the data by splitting each message up into characters and then one-hot encoding the characters. Then I attribute it to the corresponding vector - [0] for "ham" and [1] for "spam". This code preprocesses the data:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const R = require("ramda");
const txt = fs.readFileSync("spam.txt").toString();
const encodeChars = string => {
    const vecLength = 127;
    const genVec = (char) => R.update(char.charCodeAt(0), 1, Array(vecLength).fill(0));
    return string.split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0) < vecLength ? genVec(char) : "invalid");
}
const data = R.pipe(
    R.split(",,,"),
    R.map(
        R.pipe(
            x => [(x.split(",").slice(1).concat("")).reduce((t, v) => t.concat(v)), x.split(",")[0]],
            R.adjust(1, R.replace(/\r|\n/g, "")),
            R.adjust(0, encodeChars),
            R.adjust(1, x => x === "ham" ? [0] : [1])
        )
    ),
    R.filter(R.pipe(
        R.prop(0),
        x => !R.contains("invalid", x)
    ))
)(txt);
fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(data))
```

Then, using the encoded vectors from `data.json`, I port the data into to tensorflow:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("data.json").toString()).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
const train = data.slice(0, Math.floor(data.length * 0.8));
const test = data.slice(Math.floor(data.length * 0.8));
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const model = tf.sequential({
    layers: [
        tf.layers.lstm({ inputShape: [null, 127], units: 16, activation: "relu", returnSequences: true }),
        tf.layers.lstm({ units: 16, activation: "relu", returnSequences: true }),
        tf.layers.lstm({ units: 16, activation: "relu", returnSequences: true }),
        tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: "softmax" }),
    ]
})
const tdata = tf.tensor3d(train.map(x => x[0]));
const tlabels = tf.tensor2d(train.map(x => x[1]));
model.compile({
    optimizer: "adam",
    loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
    metrics: ["accuracy"]
})
model.fit(tdata, tlabels, {
    epochs: 1,
    batchSize: 32,
    callbacks: {
        onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
            console.log(logs.acc)
        }
    }
})
```

tdata is 3-dimensional, and tlabels is 2-dimensional, so everything should work fine. However, when I run the code, I get the following error:
`Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense1 to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 4032,1`
Does anyone know what went wrong here - I couldn't figure it out. Thx!

Notes:
I already tried normalizing the length of the vectors by adding "null" on the end of the message vectors to put them all at a standardized length. I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last layer of the LSTM should set `returnSequences: false`, equivalent to a flatten layer. This will fix the error of the answer.

> Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense1 to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 4032,1

To elaborate more on the answer, there is more than character encoding. Actually instead of encode each character, the dataset should be tokenized. A simple word tokenizer can be used as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663068/tensorflow-js-tokenizer/51664311#51664311) or use the tokenizer that comes with the [universal sentence encoder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/universal-sentence-encoder). The LSTM sequence can be made of the unique identifier of each token.

Additionnaly, using a single unit for the last layer does not reflect a classification approach. It is more as if we are predicting a value than a class. Two units (one for spam, the other for ham) should be used so as to have a onehot encoding for the labels.

Comment: Glad to see that it helped !